# Conditional join between different tables to combine different columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables:

1. products_taxons
2. taxons
3. tags

I want to join the table to get a column in the result to satisfy:

- If tags.tag_name="type" and tags.value="Silver" then it should contains two entries - taxons.name and concat(tags.value, taxon.name)
  Eg.

  products_taxons# 1,1
  taxons# 1, "Earrings" ...
  tags# 1, 1, "type", "Silver"

  the resultant column should contain "Earrings" and "SilverEarrings"
- If tags.tag_name="type" and tags.value="Precious" then it should contains one entry - concat(tags.value, taxon.name)

  products_taxons# 2,1
  taxons# 1, "Earrings" ...
  tags# 2, 2, "type", "Precious"

  The resultant column should contain "PreciousEarrings"

  3. All other cases - single entry with taxons.name

I have written the following sql query. It works but is there a better, optimal way?

```
select pt.product_id as product_id, concat(tag.value,t.name) as taxon
from taxons as t
inner join products_taxons as pt on t.id = pt.taxon_id
left join tags as tag
on tag.taggable_id = pt.product_id and (tag.value='Precious' or tag.value='Silver')
UNION ALL ( select pt.product_id as product_id, t.name as taxon
from taxons as t
inner join products_taxons as pt on t.id = pt.taxon_id
left join tags as tag
on tag.taggable_id = pt.product_id
where tag.value='Silver' )
```

**EDIT:** Example, consider the following table entries

```
product_id | taxon_id  
------------+-----------
 1000000001 | 1
 1000000002 | 2
 1000000003 | 3


    id     |     name      
-----------+---------------
         1 | Necklace Sets
         2 | Earrings
         3 | Bracelets

product_id |       tag_name        |                   value                    
------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------------
 1000000001 | type                  | Silver
 1000000002 | type                  | Precious
 1000000003 | occasion              | Everyday Wear
```

I want the following result

```
product_id | taxon  
------------+-----------
 1000000001 | Necklace Sets
 1000000001 | SilverNecklace Sets
 1000000002 | PreciousEarrings
 1000000003 | Bracelets
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that is what you are looking for:

```
select pt.product_id as product_id, 
case tag.value when "Silver" then concat(tag.value,t.name)
when "Precious" then concat(tag.value,t.name)
else t.name
 end as taxon

from taxons as t
inner join products_taxons as pt on t.id = pt.taxon_id
left join tags as tag
on tag.product_id = pt.product_id
```